# Merging 2 csv data sets with Python a common ID column- one csv has multiple records for a unique ID

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I'm very new to Python.Any support is much appreciated

I have two csv files that I'm trying to Merge using a Student_ID column and create a new csv file.

csv 1 : every entry has a unique studentID

```
Student_ID    Age        Course       startYear
119           24         Bsc          2014
```

csv2: has multiple records for a studentID as it has a new entry for every subject the student is taking

```
Student_ID            sub_name       marks      Sub_year_level
119                   Botany1        60         2
119                   Anatomy        70         2
119                   cell bio       75         3
129                   Physics1       78         2
129                   Math1          60         1
```

i want to merge the two csv file so that I have all records and columns from csv1 and new additional created columns where I want to get from csv2 the average mark(has to be calculated)  for each subject_year_level per student. So the final csv file will have unique Student_Ids in all records

What I want my new output csv file to look like:

```
Student_ID  Age  Course  startYear  level1_avg_mark  levl2_avg_mark  levl3_avgmark
119         24   Bsc     2014       60               65              70
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit piRSquared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

*Notice: parameter `fill_value` replace `NaN` to `0`, if not necessary remove it and default aggregate function is `mean`.*

```
df2 = df2.pivot_table(index='Student_ID',  \
                      columns='Sub_year_level',  \
                      values='marks', \
                      fill_value=0) \
         .rename(columns='level{}_avg_mark'.format)
print (df2)
Sub_year_level  level1_avg_mark  level2_avg_mark  level3_avg_mark
Student_ID                                                       
119                           0               65               75
129                          60               78                0

df = df1.join(df2, on='Student_ID')
print (df)
   Student_ID  Age Course  startYear  level1_avg_mark  level2_avg_mark  \
0         119   24    Bsc       2014                0               65   

   level3_avg_mark  
0               75
```

EDIT:

Need custom function:

```
print (df2)
   Student_ID  sub_name  marks  Sub_year_level
0         119   Botany1      0               2
1         119   Botany1      0               2
2         119   Anatomy     72               2
3         119  cell bio     75               3
4         129  Physics1     78               2
5         129     Math1     60               1


f = lambda x:  x[x != 0].mean()
df2 = df2.pivot_table(index='Student_ID',columns='Sub_year_level', values='marks',aggfunc=f)
        .rename(columns='level{}_avg_mark'.format).reset_index()
print (df2)
Sub_year_level  Student_ID  level1_avg_mark  level2_avg_mark  level3_avg_mark
0                      119              NaN             72.0             75.0
1                      129             60.0             78.0              NaN
```

Comment: This seems to be working. i have been struggling a full day to do this writing tons of code .Thank you so much. You guys and Python are amazing!

Comment: But ok, can you explain more? the best is edit question with desired output. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please advice on how I can edit this code to get the average mark avoiding 0 or not entered marks. For example assume one student ID has three marks entries for subject_level_2 as 0, 72, 0 but the average calculation is 36 which is misleading for the student's performance as the two zeros are most likely subjects where marks were not entered. So in such a case I want the avg to be 72 ignoring the zero marks. Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: sure, give ma a sec.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm getting a few error msgs:Any suggestions why?                                                           
    df = df1.join(df2, on='Student ID')
  File "C:frame.py",  in join
    rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
  File "C:\frame.py", in _join_compat
    suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
  File "C:\\merge.py", in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\merge.py", , in get_result
    rdata.items, rsuf)
  File "C:\internals.py", in items_overlap_with_suffix
    to_rename)
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Student ID'], dtype='object')

Comment: Somehow is not working with my very large actual datasets

Comment: Yes, if check [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) docs, need add parameter `lsuffix='_'` or `rsuffix='_'` so finally `df = df1.join(df2, on='Student_ID', lsuffix='_')`

Comment: or `df = df1.join(df2, on='Student_ID', rsuffix='_')`

Comment: Thanks jezrael. It fixes the error but now I don't get any avg_marks. all of the avg columns are empty

Comment: yes it gives the averages without the lambda function. But doesnt solve the problem :(

Comment: Are csv files confidental? If yes, can you anonymize data? And then send me csvs to my email in my profile? Because it is weird it doesnt work. Thanks.

Comment: I actually managed to solve the issue in a simple way like this:  converted 0 to NAN before calculation        df2 = df2.replace(0, np.NaN)   and then afterwards converted back with   df = df.replace(np.NaN,0)

Comment: Nice solution, also `df = df.replace(np.NaN,0)` can be changed to `df = df.fillna(0)`.

Comment: Thank you jezrael

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` to calculate the average marks per level.
Then `unstack` to get all levels in one row.
`rename` the columns.

Once that is done, the `groupby` + `unstack` has conveniently left `Student_ID` in the index which allows for an easy `join`.  All that is left is to do the `join` and specify the `on` parameter.

```
d1.join(
    d2.groupby(
        ['Student_ID', 'Sub_year_level']
    ).marks.mean().unstack().rename(columns='level{}_avg_mark'.format),
    on='Student_ID'
)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really good. i have been struggling a full day to do this writing tons of code. This seems to be working .Thank you so much. You guys and Python are amazing!