# Remove duplicate rows after merging

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple csv into one, it gave me duplicates like this
This is example of the csv I'm trying to merge:

blink.csv

```
account_id      kills   deaths  assists...(a couple more columns)
 1015           4        4      2
 1015           3        5      5
```

Most of the csv are like this with different data inside.
This is the result of the merge (not what I want)

```
  account_id_x,         hero_id_x,     kills_x,   deaths_x, assists_x,
0 1015,4565,5121,4687   15,71,106,87   2.5        7         3.75
0 1015,4565,5121,4687   15,71,106,87   2.5        7         3.75
0 1015,4565,5121,4687   15,71,106,87   2.5        7         3.75
0 1015,4565,5121,4687   15,71,106,87   2.5        7         3.75
1 1015,4565,5121,4687   73,86,93,30    2.75       4.5       2.75
1 1015,4565,5121,4687   73,86,93,30    2.75       4.5       2.75
1 1015,4565,5121,4687   73,86,93,30    2.75       4.5       2.75
1 1015,4565,5121,4687   73,86,93,30    2.75       4.5       2.75
```

**It keeps data as duplicates of 4, but account_id is basically all duplicates, so how do I merge the csv together without having 4 duplicate rows but keep the account_id without treating it as all duplicates?
Also is there of a way to remove _x and _y at the end of the column titles?**

here is my python code that I tried using (but gives me the result that I don't want):

```
blink = pd.read_csv('blink.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])
faithbian = pd.read_csv('faithbian.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])
iceice = pd.read_csv('iceice.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])
shadow = pd.read_csv('Shadow.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])
y = pd.read_csv('y.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])

df = pd.concat([blink,faithbian,iceice,shadow,y],axis=0).drop_duplicates()

a_df = pd.concat([df.groupby(['match_id'])['account_id'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ', '.join(x.astype(str))),
df.groupby(['match_id'])['hero_id'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ', '.join(x.astype(str))),
df.groupby(['match_id'])['kills','deaths','assists','xp_per_min','gold_per_min','hero_damage','hero_healing','tower_damage'].mean()],axis=1).drop_duplicates()

con_df = pd.merge(a_df, df, left_index=True, right_on='match_id').drop_duplicates()
    con_df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging 2 csv data sets with Python a common ID column- one csv has multiple records for a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826638/merging-2-csv-data-sets-with-python-a-common-id-column-one-csv-has-multiple-rec)